# How to order tuples by the result of the division of 2 variables of a tuple

Tags: mysql, select

How to order tuples by the result of the division of 2 variables of a tuple.

In MySql I want to do the above.

let's say i have a table with posts of a website:

Id PostTitle Content Likes Deslikes ....etc

I want a select query, to get all of the tuples order by Likes/Deslikes  (division).

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried (`order by Likes / Deslikes`)?

Comment: i tried it but it did not work..

Comment: It works in MySQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1fb7/1/0

Comment: ok, but it doesn't work with zeros, does it? I mean, if you put 0 in B, it goes on top. But I need to handle zeros on both A,B .

Comment: No, but see my answer for a solution to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER BY Deslikes <> 0 DESC, Likes / Deslikes, Likes
```

It will make sure that all rows with 0 Deslikes is places last.  The final Likes ensures that rows with equal ratios (including 0 Deslikes) are order by Likes. Optionally you may add `, Deslikes DESC` as well to ensure that rows with 0 Likes are listed by decreasing number of Deslikes.

See SQLfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e6b3/4/0

Comment: ok,it works! but it gives me the results in the opposite way. I want first the tuples with the biggest Likes/Dislikes ratio. It might be simple but i don't know what to change in your code to do that.

Comment: In order to invert the resulting list, change the `order by`clause to `ORDER BY Deslikes <> 0 ASC, Likes / Deslikes DESC, Likes DESC, Deslikes ASC`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from your_table order by Likes ,Deslikes
```

if you mean the division then try this

```
select * from your_table order by Likes/Deslikes
```

Comment: (I meant division. )i don't think it works. i tried it and got strange results.

Comment: @Vlenorroia What "strange results" did you get?

Comment: not in the desirable order. strange because the first 3 result were good (highest Likes/Dislikes) but then they didn't go by the order likes/Dislikes.